# How can I refresh a DOM element and re-run async script in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, async.js

I have an application that initially loads an image from a server based on a specific code. The dz-id tells which image should be loaded. I want to reload another image when i press a button, i.e. just change that dz-id in the code from e.g. 9 to 5. When I run this nothing happens, or actually the initial image is gone. I guess it has something to do with the script in myDiv2 that is not executed again. **How should I re-execute the script in myDiv2**?

I have searched all over the net but only found different solutions that wont work with this "script **async src**..."-syntax. Any ideas? As you might guess it is out of my reach to do anything on that server where I load the image from.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#submit").on("click", function(event){
                    $.ajax({
                        success: function (response) {
                            //run php db query that returns the dz-id.
                            //here in this example the dz-id is hard-coded:   
                            $("#myDiv1").html("<ins dz-id=\"5\" d-id=\"abpp112\"></ins>");
                            //Re-run script in myDiv2. This is my issue!!!
                        },
                    });
                }); 
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv1">
    <ins dz-id="9" d-id="abpp112"></ins></div>

<div id="myDiv2">
     <script async src="asyncjs.php"></script>
</div>

<input type="button" value="Get It!" name="submit" id="submit"/>

</body>
</html>
```

I appreciate any help on this, I am quite new to this...

Comment: what is that `$.ajax` call supposed to be doing? I've never seen an ajax call without a URL before!

Comment: Um, you're not actually making an AJAX call? Where is the url of the server

Comment: oh ... without a URL, it uses the current location as URL ... how "clever" of jQuery ... doesn't explain why you make a request and ignore the response!

Comment: what your code will do on click is, make a request for the current page, ignore the response, replace the content of myDiv1 with an `<ins>` tag - and remove the `<script>` tag - is that what you intended? I see no "image" in the code at all - so, another mystery in the question!

Comment: the url is src="asyncjs.php". Actually there is a path for it like //asdaser.c5.anyserver.com/click/www/delivery/asyncjs.php but I have to hide it from the public.

Comment: The ajax actually executes a db call on php that then returns a variable. That variable becomes the number in the myDiv1. E.g. 5 or whatever. That part works fine. My only concern is that the myDiv1 doesnt refresh after the update.

Comment: So in short: I want to execute the <script async src"asyncjs.php"> whenever i press the button.

Comment: The ajax in my original code executes a db call on php that then returns a variable. That variable becomes the number in the myDiv1. E.g. 5 or whatever. That part works fine. My only concern is that the script in myDiv2 doesnt refresh after the update